# map area js variable to php in input

Tags: javascript, php

I have a code. At the same time I would like to send the value of ell (x) (0,1,2,3) and the php variables.

Could someone help me?

```
</script>

function ell(er) {

  document.getElementById("szgep2").submit();
}
</script>

<form name="szgep2" id="szgep2" action="k.php" method="post"  />
<center>
<MAP name="wordkep">
<AREA SHAPE="circle" COORDS="11,61,8"  TITLE="" href="#" onclick="ell(0)"/>
<AREA SHAPE="circle" COORDS="34,61,8"  TITLE="" href="#" onclick="ell(1)"/>
<AREA SHAPE="circle" COORDS="58,61,8"  TITLE="" href="#" onclick="ell(2)"/>
<AREA SHAPE="circle" COORDS="82,61,8"  TITLE="" href="#" onclick="ell(3)"/>

</MAP><img src="szamegy/1_12.jpg"  usemap="#wordkep" >  

    <input type="hidden" name="menusor" value='.$menusor.'> 
    <input type="hidden" name="hosz" value='.$hosz.' >

    <input type="submit" value=" Következő "  name="sb1"  hidden="hidden"/></form> </div>' ;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
function ell(er) {
  document.getElementById("ell").value = er;
  //store the value in a hidden field before submitting
  document.getElementById("szgep2").submit();
}
</script>

<form name="szgep2" id="szgep2" action="k.php" method="post"  />
  <MAP name="wordkep">
    <AREA SHAPE="circle" COORDS="11,61,8"  TITLE="" href="#" onclick="ell(0)"/>
    <AREA SHAPE="circle" COORDS="34,61,8"  TITLE="" href="#" onclick="ell(1)"/>
    <AREA SHAPE="circle" COORDS="58,61,8"  TITLE="" href="#" onclick="ell(2)"/>
    <AREA SHAPE="circle" COORDS="82,61,8"  TITLE="" href="#" onclick="ell(3)"/>
  </MAP>
  <img src="szamegy/1_12.jpg"  usemap="#wordkep" >  
  <input type="hidden" name="ell" value="" id="ell"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="menusor" value='.$menusor.'> 
  <input type="hidden" name="hosz" value='.$hosz.' >
  <input type="submit" value=" Következő "  name="sb1"  hidden="hidden"/>
</form>
```